# How to make fs.readFile just back lines inner the scopes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I use `fs.readFile` and throw  `data` and get all file lines, now I need just to get lines inner scopes `{}`

Here's the code:

```
//index.js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], (err, data) =>  {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`${data}`)
});


//app.scss
.app {
 color: black;
  .a {
      margin: 10px;
   }
}
```

usage

```
node index.js <CSS file directory> //dummy example

node index.js app.scss //real example
```

results

```
//all file lines will print in console
.app {
 color: black;
  .a {
      margin: 10px;
   }
}
```

expected results

```
color: black; 
margin: 10px;
```

But here `data` is all file lines, I need just back lines inner scopes, any help?

Comment: `var lines = ''; data.split('\n').forEach(function(line){ if (line.indexOf('{') < 0) lines += line + '\n' });` So split the data by `\n` new line character and check if the line contains `{`

Comment: @Molda `TypeError: data.split is not a function` this err is displayed

Comment: you will need a css parser in javascript in order to achieve what you need for various css files. On the other hand if you know beforehand the structure of the css file you are going to read you may pull it off with simple regex matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that receives all the lines of the file, a split is made with the line break(`\n`) so that we can go through line by line, now we only add a set of validations to know when to concatenate and when not.

I leave this example of the operation of the function, which returns an array and a string, I did it this way since I did not know in what way you needed the output. I hope it's useful for you.

```
// index.js    
const fs = require('fs');

function getData(data) {
    let countOpenCurlyBraces = 0;
    let concatenate = null;
    let stringRes = '';
    const arrRes = [];
    const arr = data.split('\n');
    arr.forEach((element) => {
        if (countOpenCurlyBraces == 0) {
            concatenate = false;
        }
        if (element.includes('{')) {
            countOpenCurlyBraces++;
            concatenate = true;
            return;
        }
        if (element.includes('}')) {
            countOpenCurlyBraces--;
            return;
        }
        if (concatenate) {
            arrRes.push(element.trim());
            stringRes += element.trim() + '\n';
        }
    });
    return {
        arrRes,
        stringRes
    };
}

fs.readFile(process.argv[2], "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(getData(data).stringRes);
});


// app.scss
//all file lines will print in console
.app {
 color: black;
  .a {
      margin: 10px;
   }
}
```

results:

```
color: black;
margin: 10px;
```

Comment: that's great, but please can you get data from `.css` file as I do by nodejs?

Comment: Yeah of course, I just want to know if you want the answer to be printed in the terminal?

Comment: I've updated my answer with everything together, I hope it's what you need.